# Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab] ERROR: Unknown option '--output-text-symbols'

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-support-library

I import an external module to my project, its need to add support v4 library ! when i add v4 to its dependency , when i try to run my app there is this error :

```
  Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab] ERROR: Unknown option '--output-text-symbols'
Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab] Android Asset Packaging Tool
Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab] Usage:
Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]  aapt l[ist] [-v] [-a] file.{zip,jar,apk}
Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]    List contents of Zip-compatible archive.
Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]  aapt d[ump] [--values] WHAT file.{apk} [asset [asset ...]]
Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]    badging          Print the label and icon for the app declared in APK.
Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]    permissions      Print the permissions from the APK.
Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]    resources        Print the resource table from the APK.
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]    permissions      Print the permissions from the APK.
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]  aapt d[ump] [--values] WHAT file.{apk} [asset [asset ...]]
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]    badging          Print the label and icon for the app declared in APK.
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab] Usage:
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]    List contents of Zip-compatible archive.
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]         [-0 extension [-0 extension ...]] [-g tolerance] [-j jarfile] \
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]    xmltree          Print the compiled xmls in the given assets.
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab] Android Asset Packaging Tool
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab] ERROR: Unknown option '--output-text-symbols'
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]    resources        Print the resource table from the APK.
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]  aapt p[ackage] [-d][-f][-m][-u][-v][-x][-z][-M AndroidManifest.xml] \
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]  aapt l[ist] [-v] [-a] file.{zip,jar,apk}
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]    configurations   Print the configurations in the APK.
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]    xmlstrings       Print the strings of the given compiled xml assets.
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]         [--app-version VAL] [--app-version-name TEXT] [--custom-package VAL] \
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]         [--debug-mode] [--min-sdk-version VAL] [--target-sdk-version VAL] \
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]         [--rename-manifest-package PACKAGE] \
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]         [--rename-instrumentation-target-package PACKAGE] \
    Error:android-apt-compiler: [pagerTab]         [--utf16] [--auto-add-overlay] \
```

I dont know how to resolve it !
[Module link](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

Im using **Intelij idea**

Comment: Lets me know if need to add more info :)